# “To not know if…” construct in German

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure, conjunction, negation, subordinate-clause

I know that to say things such as “I know that you dance well”, one can use the form “Ich weiß, dass…”. In this case, I believe the sentence could be translated as “Ich weiß, dass tanzt du gut”.

How do you form the opposite kind of construct, that you don’t know a thing? In English and French, both languages I speak, *that* becomes *if* and it makes me wonder if it is the same in German. What is, for instance, the correct way to say “I don’t know if I can come tomorrow” in German?

Comment: is if even correct? dont you have to use whether?

Comment: @Alex Both if and whether are possible.

Comment: Still a good remark, if you can use *whether* in English, it is most likely *ob* in German.

Comment: The correct translation of your sentence would be "Ich weiß, dass du gut tanzt". "dass" introduces a sub-clause where the verb needs to be at the end.

Comment: @Alex Native German speakers are usually good at distinguishing _if_ (_wenn/falls_) and _whether_ (_ob_) in English, but bad at distinguishing _if_ and _when_ (_wenn/sobald_).

Comment: @Alex To me, using _whether_ in English rather than _if_ suggests that there is an alternative that is not spoken out loud but hinted at, not unlike ending a question with _oder_ in German. "I don't know if you dance well." would mean "I don't have the information to make a decision" while "I don't know if you dance well or not." or "I don't know whether you dance well." would suggest that you might be a bad dancer, or at least not a good one. That might just be a distinction I am the only one to make.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, your example would be translated as “Ich weiß, dass du gut tanzt” (verb in the end in a *dass…* sub clause).

If you want to express doubt about something, you put the *nicht* with the *weiß*, just like in English: “I do not know if I can come tomorrow” is “Ich weiß nicht, ob ich morgen kommen kann”. Like you assumed, *if* is used (*ob* in German), cause that sentence does not state a fact (like your first example with *dass*) but it expresses a possibility (*if*).

Comment: Just one remark which is maybe a bit hairsplitting: It's perfectly analogue to english: *I do not know that I can come* is possible as well, but with a very different meaning. The same in german: *Ich weiß nicht, dass ich kommen kann* means the same: "I can come, but I don't know it".

Answer (score 19):

The general form in German is

> Ich weiß, dass ...

The opposite would be

> Ich weiß nicht, ob ...

---

I'm going to elaborate on the comment I gave yesterday a bit to make clearer why *wenn* is not an option here:

According to the dictionaries, the English *if* can be translated (among others) as *wenn*, *falls* or *ob* in German, but just like it is not always correct in English to exhange *if*, *when* and *whether*, it is not correct in German to exchange *falls*, *wenn* and *ob*.

A rule of thumb is: In cases where you can use *whether* instead of *if* in English, you use *ob* in German. In other cases, *wenn* can be used, but mind the difference: there's a temporal *wenn* that specifies a point of time or something that occurs on a regular basis:

> Wenn ich morgen in die Arbeit gehe, ...
>   (Immer) Wenn ich in die Arbeit gehe, ...

This would translate to the English *when(ever)*. And then there's the *wenn* that expresses a possibility and can in most cases be replaced by *falls*.

> Wenn/Falls es heute regnet, ...
>   Wenn/Falls ich heute abend noch auf die Party gehe, ...

This would translate to the English *if/in case*.

To add to the confusion, please keep also in mind that *when* can also translate to the German *wann*! So the following sentence is also correct

> I don't know when I will be coming over.
>   Ich weiß nicht, wann ich vorbeikomme.

Stricly speaking, the part of the answer does not belong to this question, however...

Comment: why `ob` rather than `wenn`?

Comment: *wenn* is never an option in this case, even though *if* translates to *wenn* in some cases. However, *if* means *wenn* only if you can exchange it with *falls*: "if I go out tonight" translates to "wenn/falls ich heute Abend weggehe" whereas "when I go out tonight" translates to the temporal "wenn/zu dem Zeitpunkt wo ich heute Abend weggehe". "I don't know if/whether..." always translates to "... ob". *wenn* is simply not correct here. It never is when you can replace *if* by *whether*.

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing with the above. The correct construct would be "Ich weiß nicht, ob..."

Elaborating though, good rules of thumb for ob/falls/wenn are:

> ob -> "whether"
>
> falls -> "in the case that" (think der Fall)
>
> wenn -> other uses of "if" not covered above.

Sorry, would have ideally left this as a comment, but lack the necessary reputation.

Answer (score -2):

To negate most sentences in German, use *nicht*.

So, if "I know" translates to *Ich weiß* , then

"I don't know" translates to *Ich weiß nicht*.

Comment: Thanks for trying to give my question an answer, but the part that I was struggling with wasn't the negation of the verb in the main clause, but how to introduce the subclause.